# VS Code не корректно отображаются русские комментарии (��)

Tags: c, комментарии, visual-studio-code

Открыл код написанный в другой среде с помощью редактора VS Code, однако русские комментарии в VS Code отображаются:

// ����� ������

В настройках Configure Language стоит - "locale":"ru".

Как сделать так, чтобы комментарии отображались корректно ?

Спасибо.

============================================

Дополнение.

// Определяет семейство шрифтов.

"editor.fontFamily": "Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",

Comment: а кодировка какая используется сейчас в редакторе?

Comment: @perfect, где можно посмотреть какая кодировка ? Извините, я недавно только начал пользоваться этой программой.

Comment: а я и не пользовался этой программой просто такой значок появляется в двух случаях. 1) отсутсвует шрифт и 2) не соответствие кодировки в файле и той которая в редакторе (текущая)

Comment: второй вариант вероятней чем первый

Comment: @perfect, в основной пост добавил поддержку шрифтов текущую. Там все настройки пишутся в виде команд  в json файле.

Comment: @perfect, большое спасибо за помощь. Благодаря вашим подсказкам нашел ответ, оказывается надо добавить в настройки пользователя строку с кодировкой:   "files.encoding": "windows1251"

Comment: .. рад был помочь

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для того, чтобы русские комментарии правильно отображались необходимо в файл пользователя добавить настройку кодировки, мне помогла кодировка windows1251.
Можно поэкспериментировать с другими кодировками.

Сам код настройки:

"files.encoding": "windows1251"